# Using a timer to delay a line by line readline method C#

Tags: c#, printing, timer, delay, sleep

I am using C# Windows Forms using Visual Studio 2010.  Don't let the Console part confuse you it's a user defined thing not the actual console.  So I have a method that prints a file line by line.  I have to make it appear to print slowly so I am currently using Thread.Sleep to slow the line by line printing.  I cannot use this because it freezes up some other components in the program.  I was hoping to see if this could be done with a timer instead.  Though all the examples I see being used with a timer generally have a method being called by the timer.  Not have a timer delay in the middle of a method.  So I'm not sure how I can go about using a timer here.

---

```
public void SlowPrint(string FileName)
{

    string line;

    string tempFileName;

    string MyFilesDir = "..\\..\\myFolder\\";

    tempFileName = Path.Combine(MyFilesDir, FileName);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempFileName))
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(tempFileName);

        while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);  //This has to go
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error " + tempFileName + " does not exists");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}//end SlowPrint method
```

Comment: try `await Task.Delay(700);`

Comment: If this really is WinForms then you probably don't want to hold the app hostage by a loop with a sleep in the middle of it (no matter how that "sleep" is achieved).  Move the StreamReader out to Class level so it can be accessed by the Timer Tick() event.  This way you can deal with user interaction better and cancel the "loop" if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awaiting `Task.Delay` makes this operation quite easy, in combination with `File.ReadLines`:

```
public async Task SlowPrint(string fileName)
{
    //TODO stuff to generate real file path and check if it exists
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        await Task.Delay(700);
    }
}
```

A pre C# 5.0 solution is harder, but certainly possible.  Just create a timer and read a new line whenever it fires:

```
public void SlowPrint(string FileName)
{
    var iterator = File.ReadLines(FileName).GetEnumerator();
    System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(o =>
    {
        if (iterator.MoveNext())
            Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current);
        else
        {
            iterator.Dispose();
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }, null, 700, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Task.Delay doesn't work with Visual Studio 2010 which is what I'm using...

Comment: @user3003304 I added an older solution that you can use.

Comment: I like this solution.  Thanks for giving both current and old solution.