# StartCoroutine for delayed reaction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, delay, ienumerator

I have an object that needs time before it begins executing. When it executes right away, it gives no time in-between.
I have a function that detects when I've collided and now I want something to happen a few seconds later. If it happens immediately then it won't be smooth.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
   if (other.tag == "(your tag)")
   {
    //immediate reaction
   }
}
```

After colliding with an object with a given tag, I can implement an immediate reaction but I cannot put something on track to execute maybe a few seconds later or afterwards? How do I set a timer for an instance like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a timer to delay a line by line readline method C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888775/using-a-timer-to-delay-a-line-by-line-readline-method-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of timing can be done with the StartCoroutine() function. That is then sent to an IEnumerator for handling. Say you want a trigger to react not right away but after a few seconds. Here's our Trigger function:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
   if (other.tag == "(your tag)")
   {
    StartCoroutine(name());
   }
}
```

within our IEnumerator is where we wait the number of seconds with the WaitForSeconds() instance. wait as many seconds as you want before sending it back into action

```
IEnumerator name()
{
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
     func();
}
```

four seconds after colliding with an object, we call a response.

```
void func()
{
//execute four seconds later
}
```

Altogether, looking like:

```
NewBehaviorScript:learning()
{
   void start()
   {
   //N/A
   }
   void Update()
   {
   //N/A
   }

      void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
      {
         if (other.tag == "(your tag)")
         {
          StartCoroutine(NAME());
         }
       }

      IEnumerator NAME()
      {
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
           func();
      }

      void func()
      {
   //execute reaction
      }
}
```